# Gamemaker studio - Rooms Object doesn't stick inside the square grid

Tags: game-maker

I keep trying to put an object into the square of the grid but the object keeps going to the top corner of the square; also I can't place multiple objects by grabbing the 4 point on the vertex of the object. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should read the [official documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/) and try out some tutorials before keeping programming. I use GM:S too and this is a *really* basic question to ask.

Comment: ik that it is a really basic question to ask but i wont be a game dev if i didnt program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible ways:

1. Change `Sanp X` and `Snap Y` from `32` to `16`, place objects and then change back to `32`.
2. Move center of sprite to position `0, 0`.
3. Shift all objects (all objects in the room) using 4th icon of the room editor (arrow right).

For place mulitple objects you need select an object, press `Shift` + `Ctrl` and then use left mouse button.

Comment: THANK YOU! I move the center of the sprite to 0,0 and it worked thanks u soooo much it was such i pain to work that way.